# QGIS - exercise data

Tags: qgis, data

I´m working currently through the QGIS training manual. However, the data for the spatial analysis exercise in chapter 9.4 (http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/analysis_exercise.html) is not available under the link provided (can´t find the archive "exercise_data/more_analysis").

Somebody has the data at hand or can tell me where to download the archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this discussion - https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/246 - data could be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n7kzrv7b8fzprxp/AABrvs2LQdNdJrCsC1VA3stMa?dl=0

Comment: Folliow-up issue https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/pull/1694 . The training manual for QGIS 2.18 now has a download link to https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5evvkizuunrcs0/more_analysis.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I believe the link your looking for is at the start of the tutorial [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/foreword/foreword.html#data) under the introduction heading >> Data.

The subfolder OP is looking for does not exist in the zip provided - Must have been overlooked by qgis!

Comment: Thank you! I know the link but the archive you download does not contain the archive mentioned: "exercise_data/more_analysis"

Comment: You're right, I don't see that subfolder either. A quick google search and checking github, and I cannot come up with anything either. I would contact QGIS directly and skip the exercise for now!