# QGIS 2.14 Problem with Training Manual Exercise Data

Tags: qgis

The admin_boundaries/Western_Cape_UTM33S.shp file does not appear to have the relevant boundaries identified in the NAME_2 field (nor is there a NAME_2 field).

I have tried a few versions of the zip file where this is meant to be, but none have provided the correct result.

I am looking for a correct copy of the dmin_boundaries/Western_Cape_UTM33S.shp file that has all the relevant fields necessary to complete Chap 9.4.8 of the QGIS 2.14 Training manual?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Where did this shapefile come from?  Have you asked the data provider why it is missing a field that they (presumably) told you that it would have?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report rather than a question on StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you add the links you have followed.

[QGIS - exercise data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107136/qgis-exercise-data) deals with the same initial problem, and gives a dropbox link.

In the meantime, The QGIS documentation has been updated, and the page for QGIS 2.18 https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/analysis_exercise.html now has a (different) dropbox link.

Unfortuantely, the zip file lacks the file `admin_boundaries/Western_Cape_utm33s.dbf`. Hence the attribute table is empty. There are other versions of the shapefile in the same zip, but with only one element inside (like in the old dropbox file).

You might work on with the old dropbox file, or report the issue at the data provider. It has already been reported in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/246?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container#issuecomment-71265056 and https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Website/issues/216, but not yet solved.

Keep in mind that GIS.SE is not a bug tracker for QGIS.